# Git connected to Active Directory

Tags: linux, git, active-directory, ldap

Objective:

Setup Git repository on Oracle Linux 6. Users connecting from Windows, Mac and Linux, using AD credentials. I would like to limit access base on AD groups. I have been searching for a way to set this up. I have seen several options that allow for fine grained access control of the repository but I haven't found anything that can use AD groups to manage access.

So the question is: Is this even possible? Can someone point me in the direction of documentation that would explain the process?

Comment: I have just updated my previous answer with a solution that should work on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

There now appear to be more options:

- [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/) supports [LDAP authentication](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/integration/ldap.md)
- [Gogs](https://gogs.io/) supports [LDAP](https://gogs.io/docs/features/authentication) too

**Update:**

[GitBlit](http://gitblit.com/), "an open-source, pure Java stack for managing, viewing, and serving Git repositories", [supports LDAP authentication](http://gitblit.com/setup_authentication.html#H2) out of the box:

> LDAP can be used to authenticate Users and optionally control Team memberships. When properly configured, Gitblit will delegate authentication to your LDAP server and will cache some user information in the usual users.conf file.

GitBlit also [lists support for Windows authentication](http://gitblit.com/setup_authentication.html#H6), but only when installed on Windows, and only tested against local accounts.

**Previous answer:**

If you move your Git server to [Bonobo Git Server](http://bonobogitserver.com/) on Windows you can [use Windows authentication](http://bonobogitserver.com/windows-authentication/):

> ### Windows Authentication
>
> This authentication is very useful when your git server sits inside the company network and your accounts and logging information could be managed via IIS. The advantage of this approach is that your users won’t have to create another account for logging to Bonobo Git Server. They will use the existing Windows account they use on the network.

Doing this from Linux is *possible*, but unlikely to be easy. You'll probably have to set PAM up to use either LDAP or Kerberos authentication and then [do quite a lot](http://sethrobertson.github.io/HowToPutGitOnTheWeb/GitOnTheWeb.html#ldap) of [configuration](http://sethrobertson.github.io/HowToPutGitOnTheWeb/GitOnTheWeb.html#ldap_group). If you've got Windows licences I strongly recommend checking out Bonobo.